# XCode 4 Tutorials for Cocoa OS X Applications

Tags: macos, xcode4

There's obviously a lot of buzz around writing Cocoa Touch applications, but there doesn't seem to be much around creating applications for OS X apps using XCode 4.

Does anyone know of any resources that cover OS X Application Development using XCode 4? Are tutorials for XCode 3 usable for XCode 4 Development?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say tutorials for Xcode 3 are valid/close-to-ideal for learning OS X development, and then perhaps go through a tutorial on the changes between Xcode 3 and 4, as they are quite significant (but relatively easy to grasp/get used to/not too crucial to actual development). The differences between 3 and 4 are more usability/User Experience related more than actually changing how you write code.

Comment: I imagined as much. I've done some Objective-C stuff, and it looks pretty similar between 3 and 4. I was hopeing to see some IB tutorials for 4 that weren't ios related :)

Comment: ah, I haven't use IB for OSX stuff in 4 yet, but I'd imagine it's the same just everything in 1 window which is basically how the iOS stuff is.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this awesome tutorial series teaching Mac OS X Objective-C/Cocoa app creation using Xcode 4! The first video is found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_MJd8wqTBM

It seems really great so far. I have been looking for something like this for so long! Everything else I have found is either very high-level, very low-level, or very outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) There is more than enough there to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This one still works as of OSX 10.8.3 and XCode 4.6.1

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_drawing/opengl_drawing.html