# blogs/books for xcode 4 with just cocoa programming.. no touch

Tags: cocoa, macos

Been looking for a book or a nice blog to jump into coding a gui app for mac os x. Everything thing I find for using xcode 4 is just for iphone dev. Anyone have any books or blogs or video tutorials I can take a look at?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4 Tutorials for Cocoa OS X Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215942/xcode-4-tutorials-for-cocoa-os-x-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good book that focuses on cocoa programming. The updatet version will be published in November and should also include examples in Xcode 4

- [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X 3rd edition (2008)](http://www.amazon.de/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-X/dp/0321503619/)
- [Cocoa
  Programming for Mac OS X 4th edition (Nov 2011)](http://www.amazon.de/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-X/dp/0321774086/)

Comment: I took a look at the 3rd addition but as soon as it gets into cocoa seems to focus on ios dev but thanks I'll keep an eye out for the 4th edition